# Is there a possibility to set the default font-size of a RDLC-Report in the designer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, rdlc

Is there a possibility to tell the designer or the report a default font-size, so that all new elements that are placed within the designer will take initially this font-size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select multi-textbox and change the font size at the same time.